# Съезжает страница при добавлении новых записей

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

У меня есть такая таблица с использованием `bootstrap`:

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Дела</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="case in listCases">

                <td ng-if="!case.done">{{case.name}}</td>
                <td ng-if="case.done"><del>{{case.name}}</del></td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-if="!case.done" type="button" ng-click="setDone(case.id)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                    </button>

                    <button ng-if="case.done" type="button" ng-click="resetDone(case.id)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" ng-click="deleteCase(case.id)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Не могу найти в документации информацию по поводу фиксированного размера таблиц. Смысл в том, что когда я добавляю новую запись в таблицу, все, что под ней - сдвигается. Есть ли способы зафиксировать ее на определенное количество записей ? Например, 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично мне не совсем понятен вопрос, можно скрины?
Пока не вижу ясности - хочу дать всего одну рекомендацию: bootstrap запросто редактируется обычным html и css. Чем больше строк в таблице - тем она больше в высоту, естественно все что ниже будет сдвигаться. Если требуется фиксированная область экрана для таблицы, стоит использовать div с фиксированной высотой.